# Cast generic type parameter into array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

If I know that a certain generic type parameter is an array, how do I convert it into an array or an `IEnumerable` so I can see its items? For e.g.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
  public T Value { get; set; }

  public void Print()
  {
    if (Value.GetType().IsArray)
      foreach (var item in Value /*How do I cast this to Array or IEnumerable*/)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: T could be anything. I am checking if T is an array, only then do that. I have trivialized the problem so that I isolate it and get an answer quickly. I am writing an XML RPC library.

Comment: I see what you mean. My bad! Language blooper. I meant, if *in a certain case*, I was sure that T was an array, how would I cast it. I did not mean that T would always be an array.

Comment: Ah, in that case use Yuck's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void Print()
{
    var array = Value as Array;
    if (array != null)
        foreach (var item in array)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword:

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

Comment: This, but I would use `IEnumerable` instead of `Array`

Comment: @Moho Good point on using an `IEnumerable` instead. I'm going to leave the answer as it is, but it can definitely be done that way.

Answer (score 3):

or you could constrain your type parameter

```
public class Foo<T> where T : IEnumerable
{
  public T Value { get; set; }

  public void Print()
  {
      foreach (var item in Value)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's probably the clean way of doing it.

Comment: I can't. T could be anything. That is why I am checking for whether it is an array first.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
foreach (var item in (object []) Value)
```

As, however, you only make use of the fact that you can enumerate `Value`, you might prefer

```
var e = Value as IEnumerable;
if (e == null) return;
foreach (var item in e) Console.WriteLine (item);
```

This improves encapsulation and makes it unnecessary to change your code if you switch, e.g., from an array to a list.